# Does index on parent table get updated when data is inserted in child tables?

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, indexing, database-performance

I have a parent table which is inherited by many child tables. I was trying to time the index updates with EXPLAIN ANALYSE on insert statements but apparently we cannot do so. I want to increase the insertion rate into the db and so want to know which indexes get updated with inserts. It's obvious for child tables but I don't know regarding the indexes in parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index is created (and maintained) on table level. When the data goes into a child table, only indexes on that table will be updated. When the data goes into the parent table, only those indexes will be updated.

Most likely you don't have any data in the parent table.